# Trying to understand how "module" & "moduleResolution" differ,

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, typescript-module-resolution

###### I fail to understand why there is both a `"module"` & `"moduleResolution"` setting.

I have always thought of a module, as being nothing more than a specification *(and/or standard)* that defines the way that software-packages "resolve", *and are* "resolved-by", other software packages that adhere to the same specification *(and/or standard)*.

Maybe that is an accurate perception, maybe not, either way, I don't see any reason for configuring the `module` type, and the `moduleResolution` separately. I am not criticizing TypeScript here, I know with 100% certainty, that I am the one lacking, not TypeScript. I am just trying to get a fundamental understanding for how to configure my TypeScript projects.

---

1. What is the difference between "module" & "moduleResolution"?
2. How does the `tsconfig.json` setting **`module`** affect the modules (or packages) being imported by a project? And what impact does it have on the JavaScript that is transpilled and emitted by the TypeScript compiler `tsc`?
3. How does the `tsconfig.json` setting **`moduleResolution`** affect the modules (or packages) being imported by a project? And what impact does it have on the JavaScript that is transpilled and emitted by the TypeScript compiler `tsc`?

Comment: FYI, it's always worth occasionally looking at the generated code when you're using a transpiler just to see if it's really doing what you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`moduleResolution` determines the algorithm used for [finding/resolving](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) modules e.g. looking in `node_modules` or searching relative paths

`module` determines the type of import/export [used](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) -

```js
// CommonJS
const zip = require("./ZipCodeValidator");

// ES2020
import { valueOfPi } from "./constants";
```

For `module` `node12/nodenext`

> node12/nodenext (nightly builds)
> Available in nightly builds, the experimental node12 and nodenext modes integrate with Node’s native ECMAScript Module support. The emitted JavaScript uses either CommonJS or ES2020 output depending on the file extension and the value of the type setting in the nearest package.json. Module resolution also works differently. You can learn more in the handbook

The docs are a bit behind for `node16` but they're being [updated](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/pull/2380/files)

Comment: Typescript documentation has a book about module resolution, but I hardly can find there what are possible values of these two fields.